# Stop the condition once it executes

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

**Problem**

I am using below mentioned JS code in my PHP try catch. Basically I am making facebook app. In that when users session gets timed out it shows an error message which doesn't look good but when a user refreshes the page it starts working perfectly. For that reason I used PHP **try catch** to know whether the session got timed out or not if yes then in catch I run the below JavaScript code. I want to auto refresh the page instead of asking user to do it manually.

The below code refreshes the page but then it keeps refreshing it. I'm new to javascript can you please suggest how should I get out of this condition once it gets true.

**Code**

```
    try{        

        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => '123456789',
          'secret' => 'some_secret',
        ));

        $accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
        $facebook->setAccessToken($accessToken);

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');

        $username= $user_profile['email'];
        $fb_id= $user_profile['id'];
    }catch(Exception $e){

        location.reload(true);
        console.log('Session has been timed out');
    }
```

Comment: The PHP code is relevant to the problem since the snippet you posted doesn't tell anything.

Comment: just curious how you put js into PHP try/catch

Comment: i have added the PHP code above.

Comment: should `'secret'=> 'some_secret',` be followed by a comma, since its the last element you should remove the comma

Comment: i have managed to fix it. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(window.location.hash==-1)
    {
        //add a # if it doesn't exist
        newurl = document.URL+"#";
        location = "#";

        //Refresh page
        location.reload(true);

    }
</script>
```

or try this(will not work if the user has disabled local storage/cookies)

```
function()
{
  if( window.localStorage )
  {
    if( !localStorage.getItem( 'firstLoad' ) )
    {
      localStorage[ 'firstLoad' ] = true;
      location.reload(true);
    }  
    else
      localStorage.removeItem( 'firstLoad' );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to look for `#`, at least use the specific place provided - `window.location.hash` - if that isn't empty, there's a has in the URL

Comment: @Ian : Sorry , my bad , corrected the mistake. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: @harsha thanks for your time mate. I have added my php code as well. See above.